# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/codecs/simpletext/SimpleTextCodec

Tags: java, scala, unit-testing, elasticsearch, lucene

I want to perform unit testing in Elasticsearch for that I am using `Java-test-framework`
I am using `Elasticsearch-1.6.0`
and referring to these link for help 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/using-elasticsearch-test-classes.html
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/action/search/SearchRequestBuilderTests.java

here is the code

```
class CampaignESTest extends ESTestCase {

  def getCLient():MockTransportClient={
     val settings = Settings.builder()
                .put(Environment.PATH_HOME_SETTING.getKey(), Files.createTempDir().toString())
                .build();
     val client = new MockTransportClient(settings);  
     client
  }
 }

class CampaignTestSearch extends PlaySpec{
  val client=new CampaignESTest

val response = client.prepareSearch("dbtest")
      .setTypes(CAMPAIGN_COLLECTION_NAME)
      .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
      .addFields("uuid","campaignName","artworkID","activationDate","_source")
      .setQuery(query)
      .execute()
      .actionGet()
  }
```

I am getting this exception

```
Exception encountered when attempting to run a suite with class name: org.scalatest.DeferredAbortedSuite *** ABORTED ***
[info]   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/codecs/simpletext/SimpleTextCodec
[info]   at org.apache.lucene.util.LuceneTestCase.<clinit>(LuceneTestCase.java:616)
[info]   at testcontrollers.campaign.CampaignTestSearch.<init>(CampaignTestSearch.scala:40)
[info]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[info]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[info]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[info]   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
[info]   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
[info]   at org.scalatest.tools.Framework$ScalaTestTask.execute(Framework.scala:468)
[info]   at sbt.ForkMain$Run$2.call(ForkMain.java:296)
[info]   at sbt.ForkMain$Run$2.call(ForkMain.java:286)
[info]   ...
[info]   Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.codecs.simpletext.SimpleTextCodec
[info]   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
[info]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[info]   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
[info]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[info]   at org.apache.lucene.util.LuceneTestCase.<clinit>(LuceneTestCase.java:616)
[info]   at testcontrollers.campaign.CampaignTestSearch.<init>(CampaignTestSearch.scala:40)
[info]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[info]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[info]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[info]   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
[info]   ...
```

getting an exception on this line

```
val client=new CampaignESTest
```

in class `CampaignTestSearch`

here is the dependencies in `build.sbt` file

```
"org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "1.6.0",
                "org.elasticsearch.test" % "framework" % "5.0.0" % "test",
                "org.apache.lucene" % "lucene-test-framework" % "4.10.4" % "test",
                "com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting" % "randomizedtesting-runner" % "1.6.0" % "test",
                "org.a"org.apache.lucene" % "lucene-expressions" % "4.10.4",
                pache.lucene" % "lucene-backward-codecs" % "5.4.0",
```

i suspect the cause of the exception maybe due to some versions of the dependencies can anyone please help with the correct library dependency version to make it to work or is tehre something else which i am missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

- `SimpleTextCodec` is in [codecs](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-codecs/4.10.4), not backwards-codecs.
- You are using a jar from lucene 5.4.0. Never mix-and-match your lucene versions. Elasticsearch 1.6.0 is designed to work with lucene 4.10.4. Mixing in a jar from lucene 5.4.0 can only cause problems for you.

Comment: that exception was resolved thanks but I am getting an another exception https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45768480/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-logging-log4j-logger